# Assign a dataframe column a value, based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having a dataframe as below.

```
price <- c(287655, 456355, 662500, 597864,876545)

House <- data.frame(price)
```

I need to create another column for this dataset, based on multiple conditions. Lets assume the new column of the dataframe is A.

I need to assign the new column, a value considering some multiple conditions.

I tried in several ways. But none was a success.

```
if(House$price < 300000) then {House$A='red'} 
if(House$price > 300000 & House$price < 500000) then {House$A='blue'} 
if(House$price > 500000) then {House$A='green'}
```

How can I success this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cut`

```
transform(House, newcol = cut(price, breaks = c(-Inf, 300000, 500000, Inf),
       labels = c("red", "blue", "green")))
#    price newcol
#1 287655    red
#2 456355   blue
#3 662500  green
#4 597864  green
#5 876545  green
```

---

Note that `if/else` is not vectorized and it expects the input to have `length` of 1.  If we are doing in this a loop with each element having `length` 1, it works, but it is also inefficient as there is `ifelse` vectorized version of `if/else`

```
House <- transform(House, newcol = ifelse(price < 300000, "red",
              ifelse(price > 300000 & price < 500000, "blue", "green")))
House
#   price newcol
#1 287655    red
#2 456355   blue
#3 662500  green
#4 597864  green
#5 876545  green
```

---

If we look at the results, both of them got the same output, but the difference is in the number of `ifelse` statements which can increase when there are more number of comparisons.  It would be better to use `cut` or `findInterval` instead of nested `ifelse`

---

`if` goes with `else` rather than `then`

```
House$newcol <- NA
for(i in seq_len(nrow(House))) {
    House$newcol[i] <- if(House$price[i] < 300000) {
           'red'
    } else if( House$price[i] > 300000 & House$price[i] < 500000) {
       'blue'
     } else 'green'
 }
```